# Output javascript object as html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS object, I have been trying to output it as an HTML table. I have been trying to achieve that by looping through the object, appending the results to a string and putting it inside the table via innerHTML.

The header row is OK
The first data row is OK
However, the subsequent rows do not break of into a new row in the HTML table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr id="headeris">
            
        </tr>
        <tr id="duomenys">


            </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
var AdenTalisman = 
    {
        "Enchant"  : ["+0","+1","+2","+3","+4","+5","+6","+7","+8","+9","+10"],
        "P.Atk"    : ["-","-", "-", "-", "-", 50, 80, 135, 180, 225, 270],
        "M.Atk"    : ["-","-", "-", "-", "-", 100, 150, 250, 360, 420, 490],
        "P.Def"    : ["-",5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160],
        "M.Def"    : ["-",5, 10, 10, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160, 200],
        "Atk.Speed": ["-",10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100],
        "C.Speed"  : ["-",10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 45, 75, 95, 110, 125],
        "HP"       : ["-",100, 120, 150, 180, 220, 260, 520, 640, 910, 1120],
        "MP"       : ["-", 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 160, 320, 360, 430, 530],
        "XP/SP"    : ["-", "-", "-", "-", 10, 15, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50]
    }

    tableH = [];
    tableR = [];
    let header = '';
    for (let k of Object.keys(AdenTalisman)) {
        header = [];
        header += k.padEnd(10);
        tableH += `
                    <th>  ${header} </th> 
        `
    }
        console.log(header);
    document.getElementById('headeris').innerHTML = tableH;




    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        tableR += "</tr>"
        console.log(tableR)
        document.getElementById('duomenys').innerHTML += tableR;
        var tableR = '';
        tableR += `<tr>`
        for (let k of Object.keys(AdenTalisman)) {
            row = [];
            row += AdenTalisman[k][i];
            tableR += `
                    <td>  ${row} </td> 
            `
            }
    }



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('duomenys').innerHTML += tableR;` will:

1. Convert the DOM of that element into a string of HTML source code
2. Append a new string to the end of that string
3. Convert the string into an HTML DOM

The *first* time you do that, the end tag for the `<table>` is missing, so it gets added automatically as error recovery.

The second time you do that you end up with something like:

```
 <table>...</table><tr>...
```

and it is just broken.

---

If you are going to build a table with JavaScript *either*:

- Build the entire thing (from `<table>` to `</table>` with everything inside) as a *regular* string then then set set some element's `innerHTML` to that string **once** and **at the end**. *or*
- Use `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `thead` and `tbody` elements

```js
const AdenTalisman = {
  "Enchant": ["+0", "+1", "+2", "+3", "+4", "+5", "+6", "+7", "+8", "+9", "+10"],
  "P.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 50, 80, 135, 180, 225, 270],
  "M.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 100, 150, 250, 360, 420, 490],
  "P.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160],
  "M.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160, 200],
  "Atk.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  "C.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 45, 75, 95, 110, 125],
  "HP": ["-", 100, 120, 150, 180, 220, 260, 520, 640, 910, 1120],
  "MP": ["-", 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 160, 320, 360, 430, 530],
  "XP/SP": ["-", "-", "-", "-", 10, 15, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50]
}

const EL_theadRow = document.querySelector("#headeris tr");
const EL_tbody = document.querySelector("#duomenys");
const ELNew = (sel, att) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), att || {});

Object.entries(AdenTalisman).forEach(([name, items]) => {
  // Create THs for THEAD>TR
  EL_theadRow.append(ELNew("th", {textContent: name}));
  // Create TR for TBODY
  const TR = ELNew("tr");
  // Create TD for TBODY>TR
  items.forEach((val) => TR.append(ELNew("td", {textContent: val})));
  EL_tbody.append(TR);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="headeris"><tr></tr></thead>
  <tbody id="duomenys"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it like this:

```js
const AT = {
  "Enchant": ["+0", "+1", "+2", "+3", "+4", "+5", "+6", "+7", "+8", "+9", "+10"],
  "P.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 50, 80, 135, 180, 225, 270],
  "M.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 100, 150, 250, 360, 420, 490],
  "P.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160],
  "M.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160, 200],
  "Atk.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  "C.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 45, 75, 95, 110, 125],
  "HP": ["-", 100, 120, 150, 180, 220, 260, 520, 640, 910, 1120],
  "MP": ["-", 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 160, 320, 360, 430, 530],
  "XP/SP": ["-", "-", "-", "-", 10, 15, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50]
};
document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = Object.entries(AT).map(([k,v],i)=>
 "<tr><th>"+k+"</th>"+(i?"<td>":"<th>")+v.join(i?"</td><td>":"</th><th>")+(i?"</td>":"</th>")+"</tr>"
).join("");
```

```css
table {border:1px solid grey}
th,td {text-align:right; padding:4px}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#ddd}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Change table to use thead and tbody as stated on Roko answer

```
  <table>
        <thead id="headeris">

        </thead>
        <tbody id="duomenys">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Change multi array looping like this

```
var tableR = '';
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    tableR += `<tr>`
    for (let k of Object.keys(AdenTalisman)) {
        row = [];
        row = AdenTalisman[k][i];
        tableR += `
                <td>  ${row} </td> 
        `
        }
    tableR += `</tr>`
}
document.getElementById('duomenys').innerHTML += tableR;
```

```js
var AdenTalisman = {
  "Enchant": ["+0", "+1", "+2", "+3", "+4", "+5", "+6", "+7", "+8", "+9", "+10"],
  "P.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 50, 80, 135, 180, 225, 270],
  "M.Atk": ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 100, 150, 250, 360, 420, 490],
  "P.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160],
  "M.Def": ["-", 5, 10, 10, 30, 40, 60, 80, 120, 160, 200],
  "Atk.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100],
  "C.Speed": ["-", 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 45, 75, 95, 110, 125],
  "HP": ["-", 100, 120, 150, 180, 220, 260, 520, 640, 910, 1120],
  "MP": ["-", 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 160, 320, 360, 430, 530],
  "XP/SP": ["-", "-", "-", "-", 10, 15, 20, 50, 50, 50, 50]
}

tableH = [];
tableR = [];
let header = '';
for (let k of Object.keys(AdenTalisman)) {
  header = [];
  header += k.padEnd(10);
  tableH += `
                    <th>  ${header} </th> 
        `
}
document.getElementById('headeris').innerHTML = tableH;

var tableR = '';
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  tableR += `<tr>`
  for (let k of Object.keys(AdenTalisman)) {
    row = [];
    row = AdenTalisman[k][i];
    tableR += `
                    <td>  ${row} </td> 
            `
  }
  tableR += `</tr>`
}
document.getElementById('duomenys').innerHTML += tableR;
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="headeris">

  </thead>
  <tbody id="duomenys">

  </tbody>
</table>
```